# Firestore rules do not permit claims for signInWithCustomToken user using custom JWT

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm having a structured set of Firestore rules that everything works fine except for custom user claims inside a custom JWT.

I'm using Laravel framework and [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) with [`createCustomToken`](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#create-custom-tokens) like this:

```php
'firebase_custom_token' => (string)$firebase->getAuth()->createCustomToken(
  "mrp-admin-user:{$user->id}", [
    'isPanel' => true,
    'userRoles' => $user->roleIds // returns an array like ['admin', 'operator']
  ]
)
```

Then at the client I'm successfully signing-in Firebase like this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebase_custom_token);
```

I have a Firestore rules function that checks if the user is a panel user by checking the `isPanel == true` token claim:

```
function isPanelUser() {
  return request.auth != null && 
    'isPanel' in request.auth.token && 
    request.auth.token.isPanel == true
}
```

And everything that uses that function fails with **Missing or insufficient permissions** error:

```
match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if isSignedInAs(userId) || isPanelUser();
}

match /system/services/{serviceId}/{document=**} {
  allow read;
  allow write: if isPanelAdmin();
}
```

#### Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /system/config {
      allow read;
      allow write: if isPanelAdmin();
    }

    match /services/{serviceId}/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if isPanelAdmin();
    }

    match /orders/{orderId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if  isPanelUser() || isSignedInAs(resource.data.uid);
    }

    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedInAs(userId) || isPanelUser();
    }

    match /drivers/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedInAs(userId) || isPanelUser();
    }

    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null
    }

    function isSignedInAs(uid) {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid
    }

    function isPanelUser() {
      return request.auth != null && 
        'isPanel' in request.auth.token && 
        request.auth.token.isPanel == true
    }

    function isPanelUserOfRole(role) {
      return isPanelUser() == true && 
        'userRoles' in request.auth.token && 
        role in request.auth.token.userRoles
    }

    function isPanelSuperAdmin() {
      return isPanelUser() == true && 
        'userRoles' in request.auth.token && 
        'super-admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles
    }

    function isPanelAdmin() {
      return isPanelUser() == true && 
        'userRoles' in request.auth.token && (
          'admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles || 
          'super-admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles
        )
    }

    function isPanelOperator() {
      return isPanelUser() == true && 
        'userRoles' in request.auth.token && (
          'operator' in request.auth.token.userRoles ||
          'admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles || 
          'super-admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles
        )
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the javascript code that writes to the `system/config` document:

**Notice**: If I remove the written check from the `system/config` rule then it works and writes to the document.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore';

...

const systemConfigRef = firebase.firestore().collection('system').doc('config');

systemConfigRef.set({
  status: 'down'
})
.then(docRef => {
  console.log('System config written');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('System config error', error); // getting permissions error
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that writes to the database?

Comment: @zavtra I have updated the question with the code, but that code is correct. If I change the `allow write: if isPanelAdmin();` to `allow write;` in `system/config` rule it works and writes to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule for the system/config location is this:

```
match /system/config {
  allow read;
  allow write: if isPanelAdmin();
}
```

You're requiring the user to be a panelAdmin, which has stricter requirements than just being a panel user:

```
function isPanelAdmin() {
      return isPanelUser() == true && 
      'userRoles' in request.auth.token && (
        'admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles || 
        'super-admin' in request.auth.token.userRoles
      )
    }
```

You're both requiring the userRoles array to be on the token, and requiring either 'admin' or 'super-admin' to be in that array. Are you absolutely sure that

```
'userRoles' => $user->roleIds
```

Returns an array with admin or super-admin? I would suggest switching the rule to just calling `isPanelUser` instead of `isPanelAdmin` in order to test.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It turns out that the Laravel eloquent user model had a wrong relationship with the roles table and was returning an empty array! I've had this working but I changed the user model and I totally forgot about it! I was so sure it was working! Thank you +1!